# Where would I implement .sort() into my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I have a list of items that are being rendered to the browser and I want to `.sort()` them in alphabetical order. I've used `.sort` in other contexts but I'm not sure where exactly I would place it in this one.

In my code I had placed it after `.map` in order to chain them together, but to no avail so I left it out. Any thoughts?

#### JS snippet:

```
import testjson from './test.json';

    function loadAllCourses() {
        let jsonRes = testjson.d.results.map(function(val) {
            return {
                "Title": val.Title
            }
        });

        let allTitles = jsonRes;
        for (var i = 0; i < allTitles.length; i++) {
            $(".all-courses-ul").append("<li>"+allTitles[i].Title+"</li>") // body---to be in abc order
            $(".form-control").append("<option>"+allTitles[i].Title+"</option>") // dropdown---same as above
        };

    } // ------------------ loadAllCourses

    loadAllCourses();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use:

```
testjson.d.results.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return (a.Title > b.Title) ? 1 : ((b.Title > a.Title) ? -1 : 0)
}).map(function(val)
```

Comment: Unfortunately my data is still in the same order as before.

Comment: Edited, please check now

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: It won't let me for another 5 min, but I will.